# PyCharm Vagrant SSH custom command

Tags: python, django, vagrant, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I have ran successfully a Django application(which I made myself, following the official Django tutorial) in PyCharm using Vagrant. I set custom remote Python interpreter then created a custom Django run configuration.

If I were to run it without PyCharm I'd do this:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
cd /vagrant/project
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It all worked perfectly and made it possible to debug the application with PyCharm. Now, I've been given a real code and a real application. I can run it in terminal myself:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
prepare-env
cd /vagrant/project
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Notice the prepare-env just after connecting through SSH. How do I specify it in PyCharm Run Configuration? Neither 'custom run command' nor 'interpreter options' do the trick, as they put the command in the wrong place. It has to be ran just after connecting.

PyCharm tries the following command when ran:

```
ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/usr/bin/python -u /vagrant/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

That unfortunately does not work and project does not start. Here is the current configuration:
[image: config]

Comment: What does prepare-env do? create a virtualenv? 
When I use PyCharm in order to run a Django app, I set the python interpreter to be the python contained in the virtualenv and that's all...

Comment: @Erodriguez it is a custom bash script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrant is very powerful in provisioning your boxes. There is a [shell provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) that should fit your needs. It might look like that:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "prepare-env"
end
```

**Update**

If you encounter problems with symlinks try to use `--always-copy` as parameter for `virtualenv`